# django-plotly-dash div size too small and wont change

Tags: css, django, plotly, plotly-dash

Using Django-plotly-dash module and dash app is rendering in a very small window. is there something specific other than typical css that i can do to render this full page?

I have tried updating style of the specific div as well as updating the style in the entire page.

...

```
{% extends 'base_page.html' %}
{% block content %}
<head>

</head>
<body>
{%load plotly_dash%}

    <div class={% plotly_class name="SimpleExample"%}>

        {% plotly_app name="SimpleExample" %}
      </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
...
```

Expecting div to be full page however it is only rendering a very small window

Comment: i ended up finding my answer. i simplely needed to add ratio=1.00 i believe by default ratio is set to .2 which only shows the div in a window 20% the size of the actual dash app. 
"{% plotly_app name="NFLDATA" ratio=1 %}"

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, couldn't find where the template tag gets its style. One thing you cant try is adding a ratio argument

```
{% plotly_app name="SimpleExample" ratio=1 %}
```

EDIT:
I didn't see your comment there before.

You could also try using

```
{% plotly_direct name="SimpleExample" %}
```

This template tag allows the direct insertion of html into a template, instead of embedding it in an iframe. You will need the `{% plotly_header %}` and `{% plotly_footer %}` tags too, and not to forget the middleware should be added in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

               'django_plotly_dash.middleware.BaseMiddleware',

             ]
```

This link is helpful: https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template_tags.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with the intention of displaying a full-width graph. I have found the only satisfying option was to use `{% plotly_app_bootstrap %}` in a combination with css to format the classes `iframe`, and `dash-graph`, respectively outside and inside the `iframe`. This solution relies on setting the `aspect-ratio` and `width` attributes.

### Solution

Example file structure:

```
AmazingDjangoProject
└───AamazingDjangoApp
    │   AmazingDashApp.py
    │   ...
    │
    └───static
    │   └───AmazingDjangoApp
    │       │   inner.css
    │       │   outer.css
    │
    └───templates
        │   base.html
```

In `base.html`

1. `{% load static %}` and include the `outer.css` stylesheet
2. `{% load plotly_dash %}`, `{% plotly_header %}`, and `{% plotly_footer %}`
3. `{% plotly_app_bootstrap name="AnAmazingAppName" %}`

```
{% load static %}
{% load plotly_dash %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'AmazingDashApp/outer.css' %}">
        {% plotly_header %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% plotly_app_bootstrap name="AnAmazingAppName" %}
    </body>
    {% plotly_footer %}
</html>
```

In the `outer.css` set the `iframe`, that is included by `django-plotly-dash`, to have 100% width (of its parent), and the desired aspect ratio:

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}
```

Load the `inner.css` in the Dash app `AmazingDashApp.py`:

```
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

app = DjangoDash(
    name='AnAmazingAppName',
    external_stylesheets=["/static/AmazingDjangoApp/inner.css"],
)
app.layout = ...
```

In the `inner.css` set the aspect ratio of the Dash app´s container, and optionally configure the body (of the document inside the `iframe`):

```
.dash-graph {
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

### Preliminary setup

The static folder(s) need to be registered according to the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/). Django needs to be configured for bootstrap according to the [django-plotly-dash doc](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootstrap.html).

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with this same problem for entirely too long, I finally realized that the problem was that the template itself wasn't including the bootstrap css, meaning none of the settings that should be getting applied for the embed-responsive style applied around the django-plotly-dash iframe.  The .css files all get included properly *within* the iframe so the applciation itself was working just fine, but nothing was telling the iframe what size to be so it was running in a tiny little window on a big blank screen.
Starting from the instructions from Bootstrap's '[getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/)' page I did some quick tests and found that I could get it working properly just by adding a header block to my template that explicitly included the bootstrap css:

```
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>
```

Since none of the examples I've seen do anything special to include anything I had assumed it was baked in - I don't know if this is an actual issue for django-plotly-dash, something wrong with my setup, or just my inexperience with modern web development, but hopefully this helps someone down the road.